# Explanation of the different files in a PPTX file

Tags: powerpoint

Is there something that explains the purpose of the different files in a PPTX file.

First off, what's the purpose of the SlideMaster files, & SlideLayout files? And how do they relate to the Slide files?

Second, there are multiple theme.xml files - why? Word & XL each have a single theme file. No reason PPT can't have multiple, but what drives that?

Third, there are several notes files. What is the purpose of those?

And finally there are a bunch of customXml files. What is the purpose of those?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

Google/OtherSearchEngine "OFFICEXML" (w/o quotes). That'll bring up several possible references that'll explain the various files.

SlideMasters/SlideLayouts govern the formatting and layout of slides based on the layouts. This is more a matter for a PowerPoint tutorial, not a programming help site, though.

The PPT user can apply different themes to different slides and/or inserted slides from other presentations may carry themes from the original presentation. Or the original template the PPT file's based on may have been designed with different themes (each of which becomes a new set of SlideMaster + child Layouts).

Several notes files: each slide may have its own "attached" notes text. There'll be a notes xml file for each slide's notes text.

It's sort of the nature of the idea of "custom" that it's special-purpose, something outside the normal spec. Custom XML may define the ribbon interface or it might be anything else that the developer needed.